# design a password using sequential circuit

Tags: digital-logic

Design a sequential digital circuit that detects a 4-BCD digits password. Assume that you are using # as an enter key where the password will be decided, by your circuit, to be right (output =1) or wrong (output = 0). Assign an unused BCD code for #. Assume that the password is 3542

I tried to solve it by converting each one of them to BCD , then I made the state diagram . But the the problem is I don't know how to do this state diagram correctly . Does anyone have any idea ?

By the way I don't need a code , I want to know theoretically what happens

Comment: Add the state diagram you currently have so we can see your progress so far.  What BCD value did you assign to the # key?

Comment: If you don't know shift registers yet, which kind of logic parts do you know?

Comment: Come up with a state diagram...even if it's super wrong, it will be a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you enter a code, shift it (the 4-bits) into an 16-bit shift register. Use a 4-bit compare to detect the "#" code, and when you have a match there, latch the output of a 16-bit comparator which compares the last 4 digits with the correct code, that's the 4 digits in the 16-bit register.

Comment: what is shift register? I think we can do it in another way , since we didn't take it yet

Comment: A shift register is a string of flipflops which store the status of a number of bits, here 16. Upon a clock pulse, all bits are shifted to the right, and the new digit is shifted in. That way it will always hold the latest 4 digits entered. If you have to it's possible without shift registers, but then it becomes *much* more complicated.

Comment: Make sure to clear the shift register when you hit the '#' key. Otherwise your system is significantly easier to break into. I believe some car door keypads had this vulnerability.

Comment: @amadeus: I'm not sure that a lack of shift registers would make things harder, since a shift register is nothing other than a set of latches which feed each other.

Comment: @Samuel: If one uses four 5-bit shift registers (or 5 cascaded 4-bit latches) and has the # key get shifted in like any other, I don't think it's necessary to clear the latches since a circuit set for 1234# would only open when the last five entries were one, two, three, four, and pound, in that order.